# How to understand strange stacktrace locations in web inspector?

Tags: javascript, stack-trace, web-inspector

Sometimes I get strange lines highlighted in web inspector's stacktraces. For example:

This one points to `window`, which is an expression. Or does it point at exit from the aobve function (it is an IIFE-wrapped piece of code). Or maybe it's application of the IIFE function?

[image: stacktrace]

This one points at native methods (but this doesn't end the stacktrace).

[image: stacktrace]

How should I understand it? Was there some exception? Or is it a bug in web inspector?

Comment: That's an invocation of an anonymous function.

Comment: the first one, yes. How about the second one? `element.removeChild` is a native method.

Comment: What happens if you type `element.removeChild.toString()` in the console at that point? It might be overridden.

Comment: It *is* native. It prints `function removeChild() { [native code] }`.

Comment: Also, what's next in the stack? What is it calling into?

Comment: I don't know what's going on there.  Is it possible that you have a broken source map?

Comment: I don't use source maps in these files.